# How to transform nested object with class-transformer's @Transform

Tags: nestjs, class-transformer, nestjs-typeorm

I have entity object `User` defined like:

```
@Entity({
  name: 'user',
})
export class User extends RootBaseEntity {
  @Column({ type: String })
  uid: string;

  @Index()
  @Column({ type: String, unique: true })
  email: string;

  @Column()
  @Exclude({ toPlainOnly: true })
  password: string;

  @Index()
  @Column({ type: String, name: 'first_name' })
  firstName: string | null;

  @Index()
  @Column({ type: String, name: 'last_name' })
  lastName: string | null;

  @ManyToOne(() => Role, (role) => role.users, {
    eager: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'role_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  role: Role;

  @ManyToOne(() => Status, (status) => status.users, {
    eager: true,
  })
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'status_id', referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  status: Status;
}
```

`Role` and `Status` are also entities defined like:

```
@Entity({
  name: 'role',
})
export class Role extends RootBaseEntity {
  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: RoleEnum,
    name: 'name',
  })
  @Index({
    unique: true,
  })
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => User, (user) => user.role)
  @JoinColumn({ referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  users: User[];
}
```

,

```
@Entity({
  name: 'status',
})
export class Status extends RootBaseEntity {
  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: StatusEnum,
    name: 'name',
  })
  @Index({
    unique: true,
  })
  name: string;

  @OneToMany(() => User, (user) => user.status)
  @JoinColumn({ referencedColumnName: 'id' })
  users: User[];
}
```

Example of entire `User` entity:

```
{
    id: 1,
    createdAt: 2024-01-31T13:20:42.910Z,
    updatedAt: 2024-01-31T13:20:42.910Z,
    deletedAt: null,
    uid: '07ed21c5-f183-49ac-bba9-433118cf20cb',
    email: 'admin@example.com',
    password: '$2a$10$Ts0y.5CdnTRsP6Yy2ZZJsunNiqfRej9oNSFw7wmr.DK9z7SoFmWou',
    firstName: 'Super',
    lastName: 'Admin',
    role: {
      id: 2,
      createdAt: 2024-01-31T13:20:42.783Z,
      updatedAt: 2024-01-31T13:20:42.783Z,
      deletedAt: null,
      name: 'admin'
    },
    status: {
      id: 1,
      createdAt: 2024-01-31T13:20:42.797Z,
      updatedAt: 2024-01-31T13:20:42.797Z,
      deletedAt: null,
      name: 'active'
   }
}
```

I want to transform `User` entity to `UserDto`, which should in the end look like this:

```
{
    uid: "a103234b-1b46-414b-a380-7090d8939b4f",
    email: "john.doe@example.com",
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "Doe",
    role: 1,
    status: 1,
    createdAt: "2024-01-31T13:20:43.007Z"
}
```

Properties `role` and `status` should be equal to `Role.id` and `Status.id`.

What I currently have defined as `UserDto`:

```
@Exclude()
export class UserDto {
  @Expose()
  @IsString()
  uid: string;

  @Expose()
  @IsString()
  email: string;

  @Expose()
  @IsString()
  firstName: string;

  @Expose()
  @IsString()
  lastName: string;

  Expose()
  @Type(() => RoleDto['id'])
  @Transform(({ value }) => {
    console.log(value);

    return value.id;
  })
  role: RoleDto['id'];

  @Expose()
  @Type(() => StatusDto)
  @Transform(({ value }) => value.id)
  status: StatusDto['id'];

  @Expose()
  @IsDate()
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

`RoleDto` and `StatusDto` are defined like:

```
@Exclude()
export class RoleDto {
  @Expose()
  @IsNumber()
  id: number;
}
```

,

```
@Exclude()
export class StatusDto {
  @Expose()
  @IsNumber()
  id: number;
}
```

**The problem**:
In the @Transform decorator, when I return `value.id` and then `console.log(value)`, I get two logs:

1.

```
{
  id: 2,
  createdAt: 2024-01-31T13:20:42.783Z,
  updatedAt: 2024-01-31T13:20:42.783Z,
  deletedAt: null,
  name: 'admin'
}
```

2. 

```
2
```

And since I'm returning `value.id`, in the second iteration there is no more `id` property, but the `value` is just plain number (the actual `id`), and thus the `role` is set to undefined.

How to work around this? What am I missing here? Is there a better solution to this simple conversion from `User` to `UserDto`? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a property to the transformation decorator toClassOnly.

```
@Transform(
    ({ value })  => value.id,
    {
      toClassOnly: true,
    },
  )
```

Here's an explanation from the developer https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/3842#issuecomment-575041486